# Google+ API plus.me

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, google-api, google-plus

The question: How to use people.get with the "me" parameter?

I know how to get the json object when using `https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/{id}?key={key}`

but what parameters should I include when Im using "me" as id?

(I use `response_type=code` in the auth)

**Edit:** (fixed)

I am using ASP.NET, and I found [this link](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth2.html#SS), but the POST request for the access token json throws an error. Sending the request works but, but when I use `GetResponse()`, I get error(400). And also Im not sure if the uri that I use is correct: `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token`

---

**Edit 2:**

Problem solved. The request was bad because I used `UTF32Encoding` instead of `UTF8Encoding` when converting the parameter string to byte[] before writing to Stream. With `UTF8Encoding` works good. :)

Code that I wrote after this question:

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
webRequest.Method = "POST";
UTF8Encoding utfenc = new UTF8Encoding();
byte[] bytes = utfenc.GetBytes(parameters);
Stream os = null;
try // send the post
{
    webRequest.ContentLength = bytes.Length; // Count bytes to send
    os = webRequest.GetRequestStream();
    os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);        // Send it
}

// error handling...
try // get the response
{
    HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
    if (webResponse == null)
    { return null; }
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
    return sr.ReadToEnd().Trim();
}
// error handling...
```

he called this with the parameters [from here](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth2.html#SS), and the returned string(json) contains my access_token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sent a POST request (info [here](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth2.html#SS)) to get the Oauth2 access_token and used:

`https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?key={key}&access_token={token}`

Answer (score 2):

We have developed a .NET client library for Google+ APIs. This library makes it very easy to use Google+ APIs from any .NET programming languages like C#, VB.NET or ASP.NET

You can find more details about the .NET library for Google+ here: http://www.googleplustips.com/resources/3332-NET-Library-Google-APIs-released.aspx

The current version supports all Google+ APIs version 1, and works with API Key. Calling any Google APIs require only a single method call.

Comment: great library, I have one question. GetActivity and ListComments are getting all the data, or it has some method(using nextPageToken) to get all the items?

Comment: Looks nice - provide a link to a source code project instead of just a DLL, and I might consider using it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `me` ID as long as you access the app with the access token of an (OAuth) authenticated user. To quote from the [G+ API documentation](http://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get):

> If using the userId value "me", this method requires authentication using a token that has been granted the OAuth scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me. Read more about [using OAuth](http://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth.html).

Example: when using the PHP API client, before issuing e.g.

```
$plus_api = new apiPlusService($client); // $client is the apiClient() object
$plus_api->activities->listActivities('me', ...);
```

you have to set the access token of the authenticated user first by executing:

```
$client->setAccessToken($access_token);
```

With that set, the `me` ID will be recognized without a problem.

Answer (score 1):

> GetActivity and ListComments are getting all the data, or it has some method(using nextPageToken) to get all the items?

Each method call returns the resultset page by page. The returned object has a property called NextPageToken which can be passed with the next call to retrieve the next page of the result set.

Comment: yes, thanks, it's clear now, I just had some problems with the access token