# Access token Google+

Tags: c#, api, oauth, google-api, google-plus

I'm experiencing few issues with the new-released Google+ API to retrieve an access token...

I have been following the [documentation](http://code.google.com/intl/fr/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth2.html#SS), I got a Code ("4/blablabla") but when I send the POST request to get an access token, I get a "(400) Bad Request" response...

Here is my piece of code :

```
// We have a request code, now we want an access token
StringBuilder authLink = new StringBuilder();
authLink.Append("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token");
authLink.AppendFormat("?code={0}", gplusCode);
authLink.AppendFormat("&client_id={0}", myClientId);
authLink.AppendFormat("&client_secret={0}", mySecret);
authLink.AppendFormat("&redirect_uri={0}", myRedirectUri);
authLink.Append("&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me");
authLink.Append("&grant_type=authorization_code");

OAuthBase oAuth = new OAuthBase();
string normalizedUrl, normalizedRequestParameters;
string oAuthSignature = oAuth.GenerateSignature(new Uri(authLink.ToString()), appKey, appSecret, code, null, HttpMethod.POST.ToString(), oAuth.GenerateTimeStamp(), oAuth.GenerateNonce(), OAuthBase.SignatureTypes.HMACSHA1, out normalizedUrl, out normalizedRequestParameters);
oAuthSignature = oAuth.UrlEncode(oAuthSignature);

// Rebuild query url with authorization
string url = string.Format("{0}?{1}&oauth_signature={2}", normalizedUrl, normalizedRequestParameters, oAuthSignature);

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url.ToString());
request.Method = HttpMethod.POST.ToString();
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = 0;

// Send the request and get the response
try
{
    using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {
        // Do stuff ...
```

Comment: If you use Fiddler (or similar) to capture the request that provokes the 400, what does it look like?

Comment: I don't see a problem with your code, it looks like Google is known for giving this error within FireFox and Google chrome..You could try requesting an answer if they have a Google Plus Dev Forum.

Comment: This question's title is not helpful — it doesn’t describe a problem or ask a question

Comment: How do u get the request code??? What are the ULs that i will have to use to achieve the same for Gmail access???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the POST request. Try this:

```
string url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token";

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url.ToString());
request.Method = HttpMethod.POST.ToString();
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

// You mus do the POST request before getting any response
UTF8Encoding utfenc = new UTF8Encoding();
byte[] bytes = utfenc.GetBytes(parameters); // parameters="code=...&client_id=...";
Stream os = null;
try // send the post
{
    webRequest.ContentLength = bytes.Length; // Count bytes to send
    os = webRequest.GetRequestStream();
    os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);        // Send it
}

try
{
    using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {
        // Do stuff ...
```

This will give you a Json with the access token. Also you can see [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7497638/google-api-plus-me), that I asked today and solved later.

Answer (score 1):

The Google+ API [uses OAuth 2.0](http://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth) for authorization. You seem to be implementing a mix of OAuth 2.0 and [OAuth 1.0](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849): your code calculates an OAuth 1.0 oauth_signature for the OAuth 2.0 request which is obsolete in OAuth 2.0.

Take a look at the [OAuth 2.0 specification draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2) and try to follow the example in [Google's OAuth 2.0 documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth2.html) exactly. Or just use [Google's .NET library](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/)
which comes with OAuth 2.0 support.

Comment: True! Thank you for pointing it out, but it wasn't enough to solve my issue. I use the code of e-MEE below and it solved it ;)