# Google+ API get people "me"

Tags: c#, google-api, google-plus

After [struggling to authenticate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501938/access-token-google) on the Google+ API, I finally succeed to retrieve my info with https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/{MyUserId}?key={ApiKey}

However, despite I did obtain an access token with the scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me I cannot request "me" : https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?key={ApiKey}

I end up with an 401 unauthorised request... It's late and I don't get what I'm missing.

Here is my code:

```
       string apiUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?key={my api key";

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(apiUrl);
        request.Method = HttpMethod.GET.ToString();

        try
        {
            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
               => 401 error
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Try excluding the API Key, it isn't necessary once you have obtained the OAuth token - [People:get](http://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get#examples) _:""If using the userId value "me", this method requires authentication using a token that has been granted the OAuth scope""._  [OAuth](http://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth): _""If the request requires authorization (such as a request for an individual's private data), then it must include an OAuth 2.0 token. It may also include the API key, but it doesn't have to.""_

Comment: you need to request like: `"https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?key={api key}&access_token={access token}"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't directly answer your question, but have you tried the Google APIs Client Library for .NET?

See: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/OAuth2

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/APIs#Google+_API

The 401 error most likely means your access token has expired, and needs to be refreshed with the refresh token.

Comment: Indeed, it was obvious! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I'm 3 years late, but I found this post while looking for a solution to a nearly identical problem. I'm trying to avoid using Google's API, however, so I thought I'd post my own solution in case anyone ever wants to see a way to do this without the Google API. I'm using RestSharp to handle HTTP requests, but that isn't necessary.

```
//craft the request
string requestUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?access_token=" + AccessToken;
RestClient rc = new RestClient();
RestRequest request = new RestRequest(requestUrl, Method.GET);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.AddHeader("x-li-format", "json");
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;

//send the request, and check the response.
RestResponse restResponse = (RestResponse)rc.Execute(request);
if (!restResponse.ResponseStatus.Equals(ResponseStatus.Completed)) { return null; }
```

The primary difference from the original implementation in the question is not that I'm using RestSharp - that's insignificant. The primary difference is that I passed an access_token in the query string instead of a key.