# I am not able to post any comments in Google+

Tags: c#, google-api, google-plus

Post(Google+) not working.
I tried to implement post using Google+ Domains API v1 (https://developers.google.com/+/domains/getting-started )

Sending the request works, but `GetResponse()`, I get error like:

> The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

I am trying using the below sample C# code that I got from [Google+ API plus.me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7497638/google-api-plus-me)

```
var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/plusDomains/v1/people/me/activities?";
var googleParameters = AppendKeyvalue("access_token", access_token) + AppendKeyvalue("message", message);
var fullurl = url + googleParameters;

HttpWebRequest request= (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(fullurl);
request.ContentType = " application/x-www-form-urlencoded ";
request.Method = "POST";
UTF32Encoding utfenc = new UTF32Encoding();

byte[] byteArray = utfenc.GetBytes(fullurl);
Stream postStream = request.GetRequestStream();
postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
postStream.Close();
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

public static string AppendKeyvalue(string key, string value)
{
    return string.Format("{0}={1}&", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(key), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(value));
}
```

For creating new post and comment I am referring this url  https://developers.google.com/+/domains/posts/creating.
I tried to figure out a fix for it however the solution has not worked so far.

Comment: In the linked entry, it says "The request was bad because I used UTF32Encoding instead of UTF8Encoding when converting the parameter string to byte[] before writing to Stream. With UTF8Encoding works good. :)" But you are still using UTF32Encoding

Comment: Also, you are using FullURL for buth the uri and the post body while the linked example does only use the parameters for the post body.